# where I can find ground?

Tags: avr, electronics

there is AVR AVR ATmega32 and a board within. 
there is outputs for all ports (A, B, C, D) on board, and Vcc. 
the problem is - I have no external GND output.
to watch current - I should search for GND pin everytime. 
and now I need ground on my solderless board for LEDs and temperature sensor.

let's guess that I have no idea what is current or electricity.
so the question is: where I can find ground to connect it to solderless board?
maybe I can use something else, except MCU? (like my hand or smth :D)
[image: board photo]

Comment: Without knowing what your board is it's impossible to answer you.

Comment: Image is broken.

Comment: @Majenko, reuploaded, check it now

Comment: I'm amazed that there are six Vcc pins yet not a single GND pin. Have you tested for continuity to see if it's an error in the silkscreen?

Comment: `to watch current - I should search for GND pin everytime` - I don't understand this bit. How does finding GND help you watch current?

Comment: It looks like there are two pins at each of the I/O pin locations. Is one of the ground? Measure with a meter to a known ground (e.g., on the reset switch or in the programmer sockets).

Answer (score 2):

I've just sorted things out.
There is two interfaces - ISP and JTAG. ISP is busy with programmer everytime, but JTAG is free.
So, I have found pinout of JTAG interface and achieved GND.
There is pinout:
[image: isp-and-jtag]
<sub>(source: [digital-circuitry.com](http://www.digital-circuitry.com/IMAGES/webpage/MyLAB/Altera/JTAG_ISP.jpg))</sub>

Comment: You can check if any pin at J1 to J8 happens to be GND also.

Answer (score 1):

Pin 11 of the chip itself is GND (see below). In the photo it appears to have a decoupling capacitor between GND and VCC (pin 10). You could solder a wire onto pin 11 (on the chip socket, not the pin itself) - it might be easier on the back of the board. Also pin 31 would be an option.

[image: Atmega32 pinouts]

---

Also the reset switch is almost certainly wired (on one side) to GND. It looks to me like most of the board is "ground plane" (continuous copper) so find which part of the switch is wired to that, and solder a wire to it.